# Changing visibility of the div element using only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible without JS/jQuery?

For example: I've got three divs with background images. I want to toggle one description for each image on click. Then, after clicking another image, I need to hide previous description and show one related.

One description can be displayed instantly after page load. There will be content below those paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pseudo class :target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) and a link with href set to the id of the element that you want to show.

[**Simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q37DP/)

[**Demo with three images and three descriptions**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q37DP/3/)

[**Demo with transitions**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q37DP/4/)

```
#show {
    display: none;
}

#show:target {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#show">Click me</a>
<div id="show">Show me!</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to nicely fade in those descriptions instead of just popping in out of a sudden? Still, using only CSS. I tried with opacity 0.0 when they're hidden and then opacity 1.0 with :target + transition: all 0.25s but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @trnks_ I added another demo using CSS transitions and opacity. You'll have to take care of the positioning yourself but I hope you get the idea. Also, if this answered your question please accept my answer by click the check mark on the left.

Comment: Thanks again. I also found something like [this](http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html).
It's similar to your transitions demo and adds positioning.